# React application with Express backend and mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express, mean-stack

I want to make a web application using react as front end, Express framework for back-end and MySQL database.
I have installed the Express skeleton website from cmd express-generator.
Now I don't know how can I add react to this. In which folder should i pit the react folder or are there only some specific files that i have to add in Express file structure.
After that where should I put the database files.

It would be a great help if someone could explain where to start from.
Thanks.

Comment: Checkout my react-stack: https://github.com/lugrugzo/react-stack . It does what you want. You can fetch mysql using `npm i -s mysql`.

Comment: But i cant see the basic structure like where will be the express routes?

Comment: Where ever you want. Check the `app.js`, there is a route to serve `index.html`. Node.js doesn't force you to structure your app in a certain way.